# What does "LSB per degree per second" mean?

Tags: math, sensors, gyroscope, nui

I'm currently working with a digital output gyroscope.
Its sensitivity is given as 120 least-significant bit per degree per second.

While every single component of that unit is easy to understand I don't quite get what it means altogether.

**Can you explain it to me?**

Comment: If the speed increases by 1 degree per second, the measured value increases by a value equals to 120 LSB.

Comment: How much is 1 LSB? Is it 1 Bit?

Comment: @Hedge Least Significant Bit - the lowest valued bit in your bit pattern (i.e. 1 if the value is not floating point)